# Subquery in select Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

Trying to run a complicated query in Django over Postgresql.

These are my models:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    short_key = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=8, unique=True, blank=True)
    long_url = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Stats_links_ads(models.Model):
    link_id = models.ForeignKey(Link, related_name='link_viewed', primary_key=True)
    ad_id = models.ForeignKey(Ad, related_name='ad_viewed')
    views = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    clicks = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I want to run using the Django ORM a query which will translate into something like so:

```
select a.link_id, sum(a.clicks), sum (a.views), (select long_url from links_link b where b.short_key = a.link_id_id)
from links_stats_links_ads a
group by a.link_id_id;
```

If i exclude the `long_url` field that I need I can run this code and it will work:

```
Stats_links_Ads.objects.all().values('link_id').annotate(Sum('views'), Sum('clicks'))
```

I don't know how to add the subquery in the select statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the raw sql behind your queries using the [`query` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet) of Queryset.

For example, look at the sql behind my first answer using select_related, it's clear the generated sql doesn't behave as expected and accessing the long_url will result in additional queries.

### Take 2

You can follow relationships using double underscore notation like this

```
qs = Stats_links_ads.objects
        .values('link_id', 'link_id__long_url')
        .annotate(Sum('views'), Sum('clicks'))
str(qs.query)
'SELECT 
    "stackoverflow_stats_links_ads"."link_id_id", 
    "stackoverflow_link"."long_url", 
    SUM("stackoverflow_stats_links_ads"."clicks") AS "clicks__sum",
    SUM("stackoverflow_stats_links_ads"."views") AS "views__sum"
FROM "stackoverflow_stats_links_ads" 
    INNER JOIN "stackoverflow_link" 
    ON ("stackoverflow_stats_links_ads"."link_id_id" = "stackoverflow_link"."short_key")
GROUP BY 
    "stackoverflow_stats_links_ads"."link_id_id", 
    "stackoverflow_link"."long_url"'
```

I'm not working with any data, so I haven't verified it, but the sql looks right.

### Take 1

**Does not work**

Can't you use `.select_related`? [[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)]

```
qs = Stats_links_Ads.objects.select_related('link')
     .values('link_id').annotate(Sum('views'), Sum('clicks'))
str(qs.query)
'SELECT 
    "stackoverflow_stats_links_ads"."link_id_id", 
    SUM("stackoverflow_stats_links_ads"."clicks") AS "clicks__sum", 
    SUM("stackoverflow_stats_links_ads"."views") AS "views__sum" 
FROM "stackoverflow_stats_links_ads" 
GROUP BY "stackoverflow_stats_links_ads"."link_id_id"'
```

Comment: Hey, thought of the select_related option, but this isn't relevant when using annotate since i'm not getting an object. SQL wise it mean like instead of taking the subquery in the select statement i'm adding a simple join inside the where clause which isn't optional if i want to group by only one field (link_id)

Comment: Note: be careful about using sum-based annotations (Sum, Avg, etc) with different multijoins (many-to-*). Since the initial result set will not be distinct, sums will be inaccurate due to duplicated rows. See here: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060